# python: find the indeces of nested list by condition

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested, indexof

To get the list indeces that satifies a condition, say `None` I can do:

`[x for (x, e) in enumerate(my_list) if e is None]`

But I can not get my head around what to do with a nested list using the same scheme as above. For instance how to find the indeces of `my_nlist` where the first element in the nested (inner) lists are `None`.

`my_nlist = [[None, 2], [13, 2], [None, 1]]`

The expected result would be:
`[0,2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as the previous one just use a tuple as the items throwaway variable:

```
In [5]: [ind for ind, (i, j) in enumerate(my_nlist) if i is None]
Out[5]: [0, 2]
```

Comment: Wow - so to understand it: the  `(i, j)` tuple corresponds to the `e` (in the flat list case) ?

Answer (score 3):

An approach with `numpy` (maybe clearer than base `python` but needs a library):

```
import numpy as np

np.where([None in i for i in L])

#(array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)
```